# Dereferencing a boxed memory allocation

Tags: rust

```rust
let a = Box::new(1);
let b = *a;
```

Does this allocate 4 bytes (`i32`) on the stack when dereferencing box?
I'm assuming `Box::new(1)` will allocate 4 bytes on heap and a pointer for `a` and `i32` memory space on stack.

Comment: If you use `b` this will increment the stack pointer, and write `1i32` to the stack directly, no heap involved [with most optimization options](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PW6es1WTM).

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that may happen here.

In your particular example there will be no allocation on heap at all and only a single stack cell for 4 bytes.

But if you try next code, it will both allocate on the heap and consume stack memory after that:

```rust
let a = Box::new(1);
std::hint::black_box(&a);
let b = *a;
```

This code compiles successfully because `i32` implements `Copy`.

You're dereferencing value `a`. That means you will destroy allocation and get internal memory by value. But it's not always possible. For example:

```
let a: Box<[i32]> = Box::from([1]);
let b = *a; // error: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time.
```

So everything you can do here is to borrow dereferenced value:

```rust
let b = &*a; // b is `&[i32]`, which is just a fat pointer in fact
```

So two things happen here:

1. Memory was allocated on the heap for array `[i32]`.
2. Stack pointer was increased to store pointer to allocated memory.

After that you just reused pointer to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many bytes a type uses with [`size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) and how large a value behind a reference is with [`size_of_val`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html), which works for values on the heap.

```rs
dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<i32>()); // 4 on the stack
dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<Box<i32>>()); // 8 on the stack (pointer)
dbg!(std::mem::size_of_val(&*Box::new(1i32))); // 4 on the heap
```

The stack is already allocated, so all you're doing with `*a` is copying the value from the heap to the stack and incrementing the stack pointer, although usually this is optimized out, so it would go directly into a register.

Comment: Incrementing the stack pointer *is* allocating on the stack. There is no space allocated until you do so.